# .on event not enabling click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have put together some simple code as an excercise and seem to be having a problem enabling a click event using `.on('click');` method.

The .off event works fine but when i click the `$('#bdReset').click(function (e) {` it does not turn the click event on. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error or offer some advice as to how I can overcome this error. Many thanks

**JS Version: jquery-1.11.1.min.js**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r2qpnLw/4/)

```
// Disable click event on #srcsubmit
$(function () {
  $('#dept').on('change', function () {
    depts = $('#dept option:selected').html();
    $("#srcsubmit").off("click").addClass('disable');
  });
});

// Enable click event on #srcsubmit
$(function () {
  $('#bdReset').click(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $("#srcsubmit").on("click").removeClass('disable').css('cursor', 'pointer');
  });
});
```

Comment: `$("#srcsubmit").on("click").removeClass` is not how you add a handler

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well how do you add a handler. Thanks

Comment: The same way you did in the first part of the code. Or, just read the docs http://api.jquery.com/on/ or a tutorial

Comment: You already have two working eventhandlers attached: change on #dept and click on #bdReset, use the same way with #srcsubmit.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Looking at my code it seems that I have done it the same as the first part of the code. Could you post example please. Thanks

Comment: @Esko What do I change #dept and #bdReset to. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 Please show some effort, it seems you are not even trying to understand what we are saying to you... Go and read the jQuery documentation. The answer is already ***in your own code***, go and correct it.

Comment: The signature of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)  is `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`, so you need to pass at least two argument `events` and `handler`, `.on("click")` passes only one.

Comment: @Esko Why the attitude? I am trying to understand but you are not making your self clear. If you explained your comment in more detail then I may understand what you are saying to me. thanks

Comment: @t.niese Thank you for a concise answer. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try the sample code below

```
// Disable click event on #srcsubmit
$(function () {
  $('#dept').on('change', function () {
    depts = $('#dept option:selected').html();
    $("#srcsubmit").prop('disabled', true);
  });
});

// Enable click event on #srcsubmit
$(function () {
  $('#bdReset').click(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $("#srcsubmit").prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option. For the reason that I use mouseenter event further in the script and this is not allowed on disabled elements. Thank you anyway.